# ORA-01017: invalid username/password for ODP.NET connection in visual studio when using proxy

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, oracle12c

I'm trying to setup a connection in Visual STudio using ODP.NET for Oracle. ([found here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OracleCorporation.OracleDeveloperToolsforVisualStudio2015)).

When I login with my regular account:
username: rdsmith
password: xxxxxx
I can login fine.  But when I try to use a proxy account:
username: rdsmith[pxy]
password: xxxxxx

I get the error ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

I know the password is correct though.  This syntax works fine on sql developer, but for some reason doesn't appear to work in Visual Studio.  Anyone know how I can do this? 
Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: Username looks odd. Do you really have `[]` within username? Try removing `[PXY]`

Comment: Thank you, but if i remove it, then i'm simply connecting with my useraccount which is not what I want.  in our environment we connect using a proxy account to do development.